# The "-zoom" option slows down mplayer

Tags: embedded, video, arm, mplayer

I am working on embedded Linux.(arm)

I am using mplayer.

In general, the video plays well. (# mplayer aaa.mp4)

However, using the "-zoom" option will slow video playback. (# mplayer aaa.mp4 -zoom)

Why is it slower with the "-zoom" option despite the same movie size?

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man mplayer:

```
   -zoom
          Allow  software scaling, where available.  This will allow scal‐
          ing with output drivers (like x11, fbdev) that  do  not  support
          hardware  scaling  where MPlayer disables scaling by default for
          performance reasons.
```

Solution: use video output which supports hardware scaling.